# matplotlib, add_axes full-figure size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to add_axes which fully fits the full figure size. What I did:

```
axes = figure.add_axes([0., 0., 1., 1.])
```

...but it doesn't fit, some spines are missing. In the following picture, spines are red:

[image: Missing spines]

...but the top and left-hand spines are missing. Does someone know why and how to fix it ?

Full source code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt4.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
from sip import SIP_VERSION_STR
import sys

print("matplotlib version:", matplotlib.__version__) # 1.1.1
print("matplotlib backend:", matplotlib.get_backend()) # Qt4Agg
print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR) # 4.8.2
print("PyQt version:", PYQT_VERSION_STR) # 4.9.4
print("SIP version:", SIP_VERSION_STR) # 4.13.3
print("Python version:", sys.version) # 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

figure = plt.figure()
axes = figure.add_axes([0., 0., 1., 1.])
axes.spines['left'].set_color('r')
axes.spines['right'].set_color('r')
axes.spines['top'].set_color('r')
axes.spines['bottom'].set_color('r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It might be because of GUI frame style format. To give slight 3d effect sometimes the top and left of the frame are added with thin gray shadow line, which might result in reduced effective frame size.